# Equivalente di "frontlit"?

Tags: translation

L'equivalente di "backlit" è retroilluminato, questo è assodato, ma qual è l'equivalente di "frontlit"? Ho pensato a "Fronte illuminato" e "Fronteilluminato", ma non so quale dei due è giusto, a patto che uno dei due lo sia.

Comment: “Giusto” non vuol dire molto: non esistono regole per i neologismi. La domanda è se uno dei due (o un'eventuale terza forma) sia usato e capito da chi parla italiano. A me personalmente nessuno dei due dice niente, ma non faccio testo; in rete si trovano scarse tracce di entrambi, contaminate da siti tradotti automaticamente, contesti diversi (“insegna con fronte illuminato”) etc. Personalmente ipotizzo che il concetto non sia tanto diffuso da aver dato luogo a una parola in italiano.

Answer (score 1):

Non penso che nessuno dei due voglia dire molto in italiano. Spesso per parole singole in inglese bisogna usare un giro di parole in italiano. Io userei "illuminato di fronte". È più lungo della forma inglese ma è corretto.

Comment: O “illuminato frontalmente” o, forse ancor meglio, “illuminato da davanti”.

Answer (score 1):

Frontlit io lo tradurrei semplicemente con illuminato e basta a meno che il contesto lo richieda allora aggiungerei da davanti. Poi se si intende in senso lato o figurato direi "messo in chiaro"..